# Text Banner applet reverses that displayes text

Tags: java, multithreading, applet

i'm working on applet that displays a moving banner horizontally and when this text banner 
reaches the right boundary of the applet window it should be appear reversed from the start of the left boundary, i write the following class to do the work, the problem is that when the text banner reaches the right banner it crashes, the applet goes to infinite loop:

```
    import java.applet.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    /*
    <applet code="banner" width=300 height=50>
    </applet>
    */
    public class TextBanner extends Applet implements Runnable 
    {
        String msg = "Islam Hamdy", temp="";
        Thread t = null;
        int state;
        boolean stopFlag;
        int x;
        String[] revMsg;
        int msgWidth;
        boolean isReached;

         public void init() 
        {

            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
        }

        // Start thread

        public void start() 
        {

            t = new Thread(this);
            stopFlag = false;
            t.start();
        }

        // Entry point for the thread that runs the banner.

        public void run() 
        {

            // Display banner
            while(true) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    repaint();
                    Thread.sleep(550);
                    if(stopFlag)
                        break;
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }

        // Pause the banner.

        public void stop() 
        {
            stopFlag = true;
            t = null;
        }

        // Display the banner.

        public void paint(Graphics g) 
        {
        String temp2="";
        System.out.println("Temp-->"+temp);
        int result=x+msgWidth; 
        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
        msgWidth=fm.stringWidth(msg);
        g.setFont(new Font("ALGERIAN", Font.PLAIN, 30));        
        g.drawString(msg, x, 40);
        x+=10;
        if(x>bounds().width){
        x=0;
    }
        if(result+130>bounds().width){
         x=0;
        while((x<=bounds().width)){
        for(int i=msg.length()-1;i>0;i--){
        temp2=Character.toString(msg.charAt(i));
        temp=temp2+temp;
                    // it crashes here
        System.out.println("Before draw");
            g.drawString(temp, x, 40);
        System.out.println("After draw");
        repaint();
               }
            x++;
            }       // end while
         }          //end if

      }

     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with...

- Use Swing over AWT components (`JApplet` instead of `Applet`)
- Don't override the `paint` methods of top level containers.  There are lots of reasons, the major one that is going to effect you is top level containers are not double buffered.
- DO NOT, EVER, update the UI from any thread other the Event Dispatching Thread, in fact, for what you are trying to do, a `Thread` is simply over kill.
- DO NOT update animation states with the `paint` method.  You've tried to perform ALL you animation within the `paint` method, this is not how `paint` works.  Think of `paint` as a frame in film, it is up to (in your case) the thread to determine what frame where up to, and in fact, it should be preparing what should painted.
- You do not control the paint system.  `repaint` is a "request" to the paint sub system to perform an update.  The repaint manager will decide when the actual repaint will occur.  This makes performing updates a little tricky...

**Updated with Example**

[image][image]

```
public class Reverse extends JApplet {

    // Set colors and initialize thread.
    public void init() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }
                setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
                setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                add(new TextPane());
            }
        });
    }

    // Start thread
    public void start() {
    }

    // Pause the banner.
    public void stop() {
    }

    public class TextPane extends JPanel {

        int state;
        boolean stopFlag;
        char ch;
        int xPos;
        String masterMsg = "Islam Hamdy", temp = "";
        String msg = masterMsg;
        String revMsg;
        int msgWidth;

        private int direction = 10;

        public TextPane() {
            setOpaque(false);
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            setForeground(Color.YELLOW);

            setFont(new Font("ALGERIAN", Font.PLAIN, 30));

            // This only needs to be done one...
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(masterMsg.length());
            for (int index = 0; index < masterMsg.length(); index++) {
                sb.append(masterMsg.charAt((masterMsg.length() - index) - 1));
            }
            revMsg = sb.toString();

            // Main animation engine.  This is responsible for making
            // the decisions on where the animation is up to and how
            // to react to the edge cases...
            Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    xPos += direction;
                    FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics(getFont());
                    if (xPos > getWidth()) { // this condition fires when the text banner reaches the right banner
                        direction *= -1;
                        msg = revMsg;
                    } else if (xPos < -fm.stringWidth(masterMsg)) {
                        direction *= -1;
                        msg = masterMsg;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
            timer.start();

        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            System.out.println(xPos);
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
            msgWidth = fm.stringWidth(msg);
            g.drawString(msg, xPos, 40);
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated with additional example**

Now, if you want to be a little extra clever...you could take advantage of a negative scaling process, which will reverse the graphics for you...

Updated timer...

```
            Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    xPos += direction;
                    FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics(getFont());
                    System.out.println(xPos + "; " + scale);
                    if (scale > 0 && xPos > getWidth()) { // this condition fires when the text banner reaches the right banner
                        xPos = -(getWidth() + fm.stringWidth(msg));
                        scale = -1;
                    } else if (scale < 0 && xPos >= 0) {
                        xPos = -fm.stringWidth(msg);
                        scale = 1;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
```

And the updated paint method...

```
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.scale(scale, 1);
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            msgWidth = fm.stringWidth(msg);
            g2d.drawString(msg, xPos, 40);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
```

**Updated with "bouncing"...**

This replaces the `TextPane` from the previous example

As the text moves beyond the right boundary, it will "reverse" direction and move back to the left, until it passes beyond that boundary, where it will "reverse" again...

```
public class TextPane    public class TextPane extends JPanel {

    int state;
    boolean stopFlag;
    char ch;
    int xPos;
    String msg = "Islam Hamdy";
    int msgWidth;

    private int direction = 10;

    public TextPane() {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setForeground(Color.YELLOW);

        setFont(new Font("ALGERIAN", Font.PLAIN, 30));

        Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                xPos += direction;
                FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics(getFont());
                if (xPos > getWidth()) {
                    direction *= -1;
                } else if (xPos < -fm.stringWidth(msg)) {
                    direction *= -1;
                }
                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.setCoalesce(true);
        timer.start();

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
        msgWidth = fm.stringWidth(msg);
        g2d.drawString(msg, xPos, 40);
        g2d.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Huh.  You took the third meaning I considered, and now I see it I think it is correct.  +1 (from before).

Comment: i mean by reversed is that the last character that disappears from the right boundary is the first one that appears from the right boundary.

Comment: So you want to "reverse direction" then??  When the text passes the beyond the right side, it comes back again??

Answer (score 1):

I now think you mean 'should jump back to the start', but this slides back.  But as an aside, I would not consider an applet for this sort of thing, for two reasons.

1. Scrolling text sucks.
2. If the page 'must have' scrolling text, better to do it using HTML and JS (and CSS).

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/*
 * <applet code="TextBanner" width=600 height=50> </applet>
 */
public class TextBanner extends JApplet {

    private TextBannerPanel banner;

    // Set colors and initialize thread.
    @Override
    public void init() {
        banner = new TextBannerPanel("Islam Hamdy");
        add(banner);
    }

    // Start animation
    @Override
    public void start() {
        banner.start();
    }

    // Stop animation
    @Override
    public void stop() {
        banner.stop();
    }
}

class TextBannerPanel extends JPanel {

    String msg;
    int x;
    int diff = 5;
    Timer timer;
    Font font = new Font("ALGERIAN", Font.PLAIN, 30);

    public TextBannerPanel() {
        new TextBannerPanel("Scrolling Text Banner");
    }

    public TextBannerPanel(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
        ActionListener animate = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                repaint();
            }
        };
        timer = new Timer(100, animate);
    }

    // Display the banner.
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setFont(font);

        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
        int w = (int) fm.getStringBounds(msg, g).getWidth();

        g.drawString(msg, x, 40);

        x += diff;

        diff = x+w > getWidth() ? -5 : diff;
        diff = x < 0 ? 5 : diff;
    }

    public void start() {
        timer.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        timer.stop();
    }
}
```

### Old answer

> ..should .. appear reversed .. `"Islam Hamdy"`

See also `JArabicInUnicode`:

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * "Peace Be Upon You", "Aslam Alykm' to which the common reply is "Wa alaykum
 * as salaam", "And upon you, peace". Information obtained from the document
 * http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0600.pdf Copyright &copy; 1991-2003
 * Unicode, Inc. All rights reserved. Arabic is written and read from right to
 * left. This source is adapted from the original 'Peace' source written by
 * mromarkhan ("Peace be unto you").
 *
 * @author Omar Khan
 * @author Andrew Thompson
 * @version 2004-05-31
 */
public class JArabicInUnicode extends JFrame {

    /**
     * Unicode constant used in this example.
     */
    public final static String ALEF = "\u0627",
            LAM = "\u0644",
            SEEN = "\u0633",
            MEEM = "\u0645",
            AIN = "\u0639",
            YEH = "\u064A",
            KAF = "\u0643",
            HEH = "\u0647";
    /**
     * An array of the letters that spell 'Aslam Alykm'.
     */
    String text[] = {
        ALEF, //a 
        LAM + SEEN, //s 
        LAM, //l 
        ALEF, //a 
        MEEM, //m 
        " ",
        AIN, //a 
        LAM, //l 
        YEH, //y 
        KAF, //k 
        MEEM //m 
    };

    /**
     * Displays the letters of the phrase 'Aslam Alykm' as well as the words
     * spelt out letter by letter.
     */
    public JArabicInUnicode() {
        super("Peace be upon you");

        JTextArea textwod = new JTextArea(7, 10);
        textwod.setEditable(false);
        textwod.setFont(new Font("null", Font.PLAIN, 22));

        String EOL = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    // write the phrase to the text area 
    textwod.append(getCharacters() + EOL);

        // now spell it, one letter at a time 
        for (int ii = 0; ii <= text.length; ii++) {
            textwod.append(getCharacters(ii) + EOL);
        }
        textwod.setCaretPosition(0);

        getContentPane().add(
                new JScrollPane(textwod,
                ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED),
                BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
        setMinimumSize(getPreferredSize());
        try {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }  // allows to run under 1.2 

    }

    /**
     * Get a string of the entire phrase.
     */
    String getCharacters() {
        return getCharacters(text.length);
    }

    /**
     * Get a string of the 1st 'num' characters of the phrase.
     */
    String getCharacters(int num) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int ii = 1; ii < num; ii++) {
            sb.append(text[ii]);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Instantiate an ArabicInUnicode frame.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JArabicInUnicode().setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```